# How to mosaic/merge multiple tiles exactly, eliminating gaps?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, planet

I have multiple scenes from planet doves and I need to mosaic them together to have one raster.
I used  build virtual raster in qgis and I have smth like this

[image]

is it possible to exactly merge without having white gaps? scenes are from the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS you could try Fill nodata. It interpolates values from the surrounding pixel values.